# C#: Why I could not see my Class (that was created dynamically) properties

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, builder

I am going to create a class builder class. It work properly and my class is created base on data that I need. But I could not see the properties that were added to class.

it is my class builder class:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace aitClassBuilder
{
    public interface IclassBuilder
    {
        float Read(Int32 first, Int32 second);
        string Write();
    }
    public class ClassBuilder : IclassBuilder
    {
        AssemblyName asemblyName;
        public ClassBuilder(string ClassName, string ClassId)
        {
            this.asemblyName = new AssemblyName(ClassName);
        }
        public object CreateObject()
        {
            TypeBuilder DynamicClass = this.CreateClass();
            this.CreateConstructor(DynamicClass);


        CreateProperty(DynamicClass, "ColumnId", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        CreateProperty(DynamicClass, "ColumnName", Type.GetType("System.String"));

            Type type = DynamicClass.CreateType();
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        private TypeBuilder CreateClass()
        {
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(this.asemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(this.asemblyName.FullName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, null);
            return typeBuilder;
        }
        private void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
        {
            typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
        }
        private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
            ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
            getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { propertyType });
            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();
            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }
        public float Read(Int32 first, Int32 second)
        {
            return first + second;
        }
        public string Write()
        {
            string result = "";
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and I use from the class like this:

```
        aitClassBuilder.ClassBuilder myCls = 
                      new   ClassBuilder("Sys_Columns", "1003");
        object myTbl = myCls.CreateObject();
        MessageBox.Show(myTbl.ColumnID);
```

at end of this code when I want get access to ColumnID property of my class, an Error took place. But when I add the class to watch window, I could see that the  properties were added to my class. I dont know why?
Could you help me please?

The error detail is:
Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnID' and no extension method 'ColumnID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   FormSample  E:\New Hafiz\aitClassBuilder\FormSample\Form1.cs    29  Active

Comment: And the exception was..

Comment: You could have probably asked this question with about 10 lines of code or less

Comment: You also didn't add the error message, which is always annoying

Comment: it is an Error:'object' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnID' and no extension method 'ColumnID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please 1. format your code, 2. put the exception details (including showing where it was thrown) *in the question*.

Comment: Dear Saruman I am very beginner at C# and I think that if I post my class it could be helpfull.

Comment: Its because you are trying to get a property from myTbl of type object. You need to cast myTbl properly for it to function.

Comment: Sorry but as I say, I am very beginner at C#. How could I do this?

Comment: _Sorry but as I say, I am very beginner at C#_ - for beginner, I afraid you choose to complicated approach for your problem?

Comment: I am beginner at c# but I am not beginner programmer. I know I choose a complicate approach, but I think it is possible and very much better than I create more that 300 classes for my purpose.

Comment: Change `object` to `dynamic`.  There is only a real point to this code when you write more of it.  Don't create your own ORM, it has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening there?

0_o.

Why do you generate a whole new class on the fly rather than create yet another `Dictionary<string, object>`? In case you prefer to stick to strong types (which I assume you do, otherwise why C# ever needed?), an extension method `TResult TryGetValue<TResult>(this Dictionary<string, object> @this, string key)` might be declared.

Hence 95% of code you showed up will vanish and the problem you started with will... just disappear.

Comment: Hi thank you so much. This solution is perfect and works wonderful. As you said 95% of code should be vanished. Thank you again.

Comment: @Farzin luckily you haven't started your own OS yet, so I was just in time.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates the `object` type does not have a property called `ColumnID`. Due to the fact that you cannot cast the object to the actual type, you have to use the [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) keyword here. So your code will be:

```
dynamic myTbl = myCls.CreateObject();
MessageBox.Show(myTbl.ColumnID);
```

Note that you won't have any compile time checks on the types of the properties using this approach.

Comment: And then your C# throughout becomes `dynamic` and you find yourself coding some weird `Java-#-Script` in Visual Studio,

Comment: Well, this is exactly what already happened by the OPs  requirements.

Comment: The only possibility to avoid that `dynamic` hell would be to introduce an interface, written in the source code, to the dynamically created class and then casting to that interface.

Comment: I try to use this. This time the code was compiled and and at the line that MessageBox.Show(NyTbl.ColumnID); this Exception took place. An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: 'Sys_Columns' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnID'

Comment: There is one more solution, actually. Redesign things such that no weird and indeed unnecessary stuff ever happens.

Comment: Finally I should thank you all people. However the next answer by Mr.  Сергей Боголюбов solved my problem but this answer and its comments open a new vision about .net programming for me.

Comment: @Farzin Did you make sure that your object has such a property? I tested your code with generated properties `Test1` - `Test10` and everythings works fine. However i agree with the others that you should try to redesign your solution.

Comment: I change object to type and run my code again. I try with dynamic too. All properties were added to class by I couldn't have access to them.

Comment: @Streamline  please tell me how it worked fine? how you could have access to the class properties? With Reflection?

Comment: @Farzin, don't do `dynamic` unless it is really necessary. You're loosing strong type support.

Comment: @Farzin I replaced your `for` loop that created the properties with one that created the Test0 - 10 properties and could access them afterwards as it's supposed to be. But i noticed you changed `ColumnID` to `ColumnId` in your code where you create the properties. Maybe that's where the error comes from.

Comment: @Stresmline You are right. I change code like this and it works fine.             int myInt;
            myInt  = myTbl.ColumnID;
            MessageBox.Show(myInt.ToString ()); It seems that I didn't implement something to cast Integer value to string. however I changed my design as Сергей Боголюбов solution.

Comment: And finally Thank you all people for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your object to (Sys_Columns).

```
Sys_Columns myTbl = (Sys_Columns)myCls.CreateObject();
```

Comment: Actually I don't have any Sys_Columns class at design mode. I try this but this Error appear: The type or namespace name 'Sys_Columns' could not be found

Comment: Where is baseData defined?

Comment: Sorry I change code. It is a List of my Properties. I replace it with a 2 specific properties.